# Count the number of visible rows in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0

I would like to know how many rows are actually displayed by a WPF `DataGrid`.

I tried looping over `DataGridRow` and checking `IsVisible`, but it seems that rows report `IsVisible = true` even when they are not in the `DataGrid` viewport.

How can I count the number of visible rows correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked this question also on MSDN forum and got a [good answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7f6285ed-a884-43b0-8c58-154d8c13ab48/):

```
private bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container) {
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;
    Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}
```

Comment: return sentence should be changed to:
return rect.Top < bounds.Top && rect.Bottom > bounds.Bottom; 
Then it will check if the whole item is displayed rather then top left corner or bottom right corner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with rows showing as `Visible = true` even when they weren't.

Trying to come up with a solution, I posted this question: [Visible rows in DataGrid is off by 1 (counted using ContainerFromItem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548360/visible-rows-in-datagrid-is-off-by-1-counted-using-containerfromitem/27550076#27550076).

Here's what worked for me:

```
uint VisibleRows = 0;
var TicketGrid = (DataGrid) MyWindow.FindName("TicketGrid");

foreach(var Item in TicketGrid.Items) {
    var Row = (DataGridRow) TicketGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Item);

    if(Row != null) {
        if(Row.TransformToVisual(TicketGrid).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y + Row.ActualHeight >= TicketGrid.ActualHeight) {
            break;
        }

        VisibleRows++;
    }
}
```

For further guidance, there are some `/* comments */` in my answer on the linked question, as well as a thread of user comments on the question itself that led to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

a simple hack come to mind,

loop over all rows and check if item has a container?

```
dataGrid.GetContainerFromItem(dataGrid.Items[row]);
```

hope this helps

Comment: This does not work. In fact, in my loop I was using `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex` and some items that are not displayed still have container.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for another xaml element just add a reference via "ElementName" and the property via "Items.Count" to your content property(in this case "Text"). You might also  use a converter to parse the value.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ComponentDataGrid, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}"/>
```