# Finding indexes of first and last items currently displayed in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

In my DataGrid I would like to find the first and last item indexes currently being displayed. This is not quite as easy as when dealing with a plain old ListBox and Scrollviewer.

Could someone tell me how please?

Comment: Paste some code. How Your DataGrid looks now?

Comment: Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979827/count-the-number-of-visible-rows-in-a-datagrid It explains how to find visible items in DataGrid. Having this information you can find indexes of the first and the last visible item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your ItemSource & get first & last `DataGridRow`. It is not a good solution but you can try like this.

```
DataGridRow firstRow = null;
DataGridRow lastRow = null;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    if (row != null)
    {
        firstRow = row;
        while (row != null)
        {
            row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(++i);
        }
        lastRow = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i - 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that, that would be quite slow with the large number of items I have.  I was hoping somewhere in the datagrids descendants there would be an items offset and number of items shown. Even with what Michal linked to above it would be too slow.

Comment: You will have to find solution using this http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemContainerGenerator.cs,1b7909b08c58ddd0 this reference....